# Discrete Time Signals - Time Scaling and Time Reversal

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, time-series, scaling

On the top graph, we can see a discrete-time signal $x[n]$.

1. I don't understand how for the signal $x[3-n]$, the impulses with magnitude $1$ still are at the positive indices $n = 1, 2, 3, 4$. Why  are they not at negative indices side since we have no positive $n$ this time, but have negative $n$ (see Figure 1.22(b)).
2. Why when we take $x[3n]$ most of impulses are gone? (Figure 1.22(c))

Are the operations like time-scaling, time-reversal, time-shifting, on discrete time signals different?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1) Reversal and time advance

$x[3-n]$ combines two operations:

- Time reversal: $x[n] \rightarrow x[-n]$:
- Time advance: $x[-n] \rightarrow x[-n +\tt{3}]$

###### Visually

Look at $x[n]$ and imagine flipping it around $n=\tt{0}$. That's **time reversal**. The sample at $n=\tt{-4}$, with magnitude $-1$, is now at index $n = \tt{4}$. Same goes for sample at $n=\tt{-3}$, with magnitude $-1/2$, which is now at index $n = \tt{3}$. Now **advance** this signal by $\tt{3}$ samples: that sample at $n=\tt{4}$ with magnitude $-1$ is now at $n=\tt{4+3} = 7$. That sample at $n=\tt{3}$ with magnitude $-1/2$ is now at $n=\tt{3+3} = 6$, etc

###### Write it out

You can do this for every index: let's write out the values for $x[n]$ where it is defined, i.e. for $-5 \leq n \leq 5$:

\begin{align}
&n &\quad &x[n]\\
\hline
-&\tt{5} &\quad &0\\
-&\tt{4} &\quad -&1\\
-&\tt{3} &\quad -&1/2\\
-&\tt{2} &\quad &1/2\\
-&\tt{1} &\quad &1\\
&\tt{0} &\quad &1\\
&\tt{1} &\quad &1\\
&\tt{2} &\quad &1\\
&\tt{3} &\quad &1/2\\
&\tt{4} &\quad &0\\
&\tt{5} &\quad &0\\
\end{align}

Now let's look at $x[3-n]$. I'll start at $n = -5$, even though for that value, $x[3-n] = x[8]$ is $\text{undefined}$:
\begin{align}
&n &\quad &3-n &\quad &x[3-n]\\
\hline
-&\tt{5} &\quad &\tt{3} - \tt{(-5) = 8}&\quad &x[8] \text{ is undefined}\\
-&\tt{4} &\quad &\tt{3} - \tt{(-4) = 7}&\quad &\text{undefined}\\
-&\tt{3} &\quad &\tt{3} - \tt{(-3) = 6}&\quad &\text{undefined}\\
-&\tt{2} &\quad &\tt{3} - \tt{(-2) = 5}&\quad &0\\
-&\tt{1} &\quad &\tt{4}&\quad &0\\
&\tt{0} &\quad &\tt{3}&\quad &1/2\\
&\tt{1} &\quad &\tt{2}&\quad &1\\
&\tt{2} &\quad &\tt{1} &\quad &1\\
&\tt{3} &\quad &\tt{0}&\quad &1\\
&\tt{4} &\quad &\tt{-1}&\quad &1\\
&\tt{5} &\quad &\tt{-2}&\quad &1/2\\
&\tt{6} &\quad &\tt{-3}&\quad -&1/2\\
&\tt{7} &\quad &\tt{-4}&\quad -&1\\
&\tt{8} &\quad &\tt{-5}&\quad &0\\
\end{align}

### 2) Time Scaling

$x[Kn]$ is called *decimation* by the *scaling factor* $K>1$ (it's called *expansion* if $0<K<1$).

In your case, you therefore have time *decimation* by scaling factor $3$: $x[3n]$
This operation only keeps every 3 sample.

Let's write it out. Again, I'll start at $n = -5$, even though for that value, $x[3n] = x[-15]$ is $\text{undefined}$:

\begin{align}
&n &\quad &3n &\quad &x[3n]\\
\hline
-&\tt{5} &\quad &\tt{3} \times \tt{(-5) = -15}&\quad &x[-15]\text{ is undefined}\\
-&\tt{4} &\quad &\tt{3} \times \tt{(-4) = -12}&\quad &\text{undefined}\\
-&\tt{3} &\quad &\tt{3} \times\tt{(-3) = -9}&\quad &\text{undefined}\\
-&\tt{2} &\quad &\tt{3} \times\tt{(-2) = -6}&\quad &\text{undefined}\\
-&\tt{1} &\quad -&\tt{3}&\quad -&1/2\\
&\tt{0} &\quad &\tt{0}&\quad &1\\
&\tt{1} &\quad &\tt{3}&\quad &1/2\\
&\tt{2} &\quad &\tt{6} &\quad &\text{undefined}\\
&\tt{3} &\quad &\tt{9}&\quad &\text{undefined}\\
&\tt{4} &\quad &\tt{12}&\quad &\text{undefined}\\
&\tt{5} &\quad &\tt{15}&\quad &\text{undefined}\\
\end{align}